# Getting invalid_grant error when make post request to my oauth provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I use the [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) gem to introduce OAuth 2 provider functionality to my Rails application. I added the gem to gemfile, configure it and trying to make post request to get access token as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples#post---oauthtoken).

I sent post request to this url - http://localhost:3000/oauth/token
with this parameters:

```
client_id=c094523a20444ee3362e8eb33e08b5266cfb6486babe9f918c0c88104e67f6c0&client_secret=d6cebe57e475e685beb2401108438991e94f0078152d52a2da4d5f1307a4729c&code=c2f56975ba6970634deef1e256faa5de5b146f794f37b3c59f3b5111d6810ef6&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

But I get the error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
```

My doorkeeper initializer:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use (needs plugins)
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || warden.authenticate!(scope: :user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Comment: yes, I'm using Devise. Also Rails version is 5.1.5 maybe it's important.

Comment: It creates a new token but it does not respond properly.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem with doorkeeper 4.3+
The solution is to use doorkeeper 4.2.6

Comment: kindly consider further explaining your answer